# How to find the numerator and the denominator of a rational in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, rational-number

How to find the numerator and the denominator of a rational in Clojure?

How can I convert a rational to a pair of ints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the [`numerator`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/numerator) and [`denominator`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/denominator) functions.

```
> (numerator (/ 2 3))
2
> (denominator (/ 2 3))
3
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use numerator and denominator functions to extract the pair of numbers like so

```
(defn ratio-to-vector [r]
 ((juxt numerator denominator) r))
```

For example

> (ratio-to-vector 22/7) ;=> [22 7]

Note that in this form the function will break on other numerical types.